# Django : Many TO many relationship for same table

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a scenario .

I have many  users in my application and everyone  one have there own `(Trusted Circle)`.Trusted Circle is shomewhat similar to the close friend .

I am having a confusion here .

What is the best way to implement the trusted circle per user  .Trusted circle users are also like user in my app .

I heared about `ManyToMany`  field with `self` attribute .It  worth to use in my application to maintain the trusted circle per user .

Please suggest me some other alternatives also if possible .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a Django model with ManyToMany relationsship with self through a Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880489/how-do-i-write-a-django-model-with-manytomany-relationsship-with-self-through-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Classical approach** will be:

```
1 user circle can contains n users
1 user may be in n user circles.
```

This is a N:M relationship.

But, because this is for django, my **django design suggestion** is:

```
1:1 relationship to circle:
      1 user has 1 circle   

N:M relationship to users circle:
      1 circle can contains n users
      1 user may be in n circles.
```

**Circle** with one to one and m2m Relationhips:

```
class Circle(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

To **create user's circle** on create user:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def create_circle(sender, **kw):
    user = kw["instance"]
    if kw["created"]:
        c = Circle(user=user)
        c.save()

post_save.connect(create_circle, sender=User)
```

Enjoy and enroll me on your trusted circle ;)

Answer (score 0):

To add many to many relationship to a single table, add a different `related_name` for the fields which has many to many relationship with a single table.

For eg:

```
class A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ManyToManyField('B', related_name='field1')
    field2 = models.ManyToManyField('B', related_name='field2')
    field3 = models.ManyToManyField('B', related_name='field3')

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```